# Полупрозрачная рамка вокруг карты с border-radius

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как можно реализовать подобную рамку вместе со свойством border-radius?
То что должно получиться: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgk5W.png

```css
.map {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map:before,
.map:after,
.map-wrap:before,
.map-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.6);
}

.map:before,
.map:after {
  width: 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.map:after {
  right: 0;
}

.map-wrap:before,
.map-wrap:after {
  height: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.map-wrap:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.map iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="map-wrap">
    <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCUjn-VQkC" width="100%" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить отдельный блок c абсолютным позиционированиием, который будет повторять форму враппера c классом `map`. Но чтобы он не перекрывал компонент карты и не мешал, этому блоку с рамкой нужно добавить свойство `pointer-events` со значением `none`, тогда он не сможет стать целью событий указателя и все эвенты(click, mousemove и т.д) будут проходить "сквозь" него.

```css
.map {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map, .map-border {
  border-radius: 100px 0px;
}

.map iframe {
  display: block;
}

.map-border {
  border: 10px solid #00000030;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="map-wrap">
    <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCUjn-VQkC" width="100%" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="map-border"></div>
</div>
```

Топик на MDN - [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)